# Actionsript/Flex String replace for <

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, string, actionscript

I have a string like `"My <color>"`
I want to replace `"<color>"` with `"Orange"`.
I did

```
str = str.replace("<color>","Orange");
```

but it doesn't work.

How to do it?

Comment: You want to... replace `""`, or nothing, with Orange? Or did you want to replace the white space, `" "`?

Comment: I have modified the question.
SO automatically removes "less than sign"

Comment: It works great for me. (select the code and press ctrl+k to format it - this way it won't hide your angle brackets either).

Comment: Are you sure what you wrote doesn't work for you? "It works on my machine".

Comment: May be a dumb question, but are you sure you created an AS3 file? .replace isn't a string method in AS2 from my recollection. Otherwise, your pasted code works fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to edited post:**

So replace returns a copy of "replaced" string, it does not modify the original:

```
var string:String = "My <color>";
var replaced:String = string.replace("<color>", "Orange");
// My <color> My Orange
trace(string, replaced);
```

So you could do:

```
var str:String = "My <color>";
str = str.replace("<color>", "Orange");
// My Orange
trace(str);
```

*Then* str would be "My Orange"

Which is what your code says it does, but I think you didn't paste what you wrote or you have an error elsewhere in your program.

---

**Answer to OP:**

"" is an empty string, so you're basically saying "replace empty with Orange". A space is not empty. If you want "MyOrange", you'll want to use " " instead of "":

```
var str:String = "My ";
// MyOrange
trace(str.replace(" ", "Orange"));
```

If you want "My Orange" just append "Orange" to your string.

```
var str:String = "My ";
str += "Orange"
// My Orange
trace(str);
```

Can you provide some more input as to what your intended output should be so we can provide a more accurate answer?

Comment: His angle brackets were stripped off.. check the edited question.